# delete a row from a table and get the remaining rows in one query SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to delete a row from a table and return the remaining rows that are in the table in an SQL database. I can easily accomplish this in two queries, but I would like to do this in one query if possible, and am struggling to do so.

The current implementation that I have is having two separate queries:

```sql
DELETE FROM posts 
WHERE rowid = ?
```

and

```sql
SELECT posts.rowid, circle, description, timestamp
FROM posts
WHERE author = ?
ORDER BY
timestamp DESC
```

My attempt at trying to combine the queries like so:

```sql
DELETE FROM posts 
WHERE rowid = ?;
SELECT posts.rowid, circle, description, timestamp
FROM posts
WHERE author = ?
ORDER BY
timestamp DESC
```

with the semicolon separating the queries resulted in no rows being returned when there was definitely still rows in the table.

This is test data that I have in the table while executing the query with the semicolon separating the queries

```
row 1: circle="first circle", author="me@example.com", description="first", timestamp=<timestamp taken by sql> 
row 2: circle="first circle", author="me@example.com", description="second", timestamp=<timestamp taken by sql>
```

So the `WHERE` clause should not filter out all data, as the authors for the test data are all the same, and should return row 2 when deleting the first row, however it returns no rows

Another thing I'd like to point out is that when I attempt the second method, with a semicolon between the two queries, it returns no rows. But, when I query after using that method using this query:

```sql
SELECT posts.rowid, circle, description, timestamp
FROM posts
WHERE author = ?
ORDER BY
timestamp DESC
```

it returns all the rows that I expect to return from the delete + select query, confirming that the `DELETE` part of the query does not delete all the rows, and should return the remaining rows of the table

For more context, I am using the `databases/sql` package in go, and am using the `sql.DB.QueryContext` method to run the queries.

Here are the functions I am using to execute the queries:

The struct I am using that holds the `sql.DB` struct and context

```golang
type CirclesDB struct {
    db  *sql.DB
    ctx context.Context
}
```

Delete:

```golang
func (cdb *CirclesDB) DeletePost(id int64) error  {
    _, err := cdb.exec(
        `DELETE FROM posts
        WHERE rowid = ?
        `,
        id,
    )

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Delete with semicolon between select (this returns 0 rows):

```golang
func (cdb *CirclesDB) DeletePostAndReturnRemainingByAuthor(id int64, author string) ([]post.UserPost, error) {
    query := `
        DELETE FROM posts
        WHERE rowid = ?;
        SELECT posts.rowid, circle, description, timestamp
        FROM posts
        WHERE author = ?
        ORDER BY
        timestamp DESC
    `
    rows, err := cdb.query(query, id, author)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    var posts []post.UserPost
    for rows.Next() {
        var post post.UserPost
        if err := rows.Scan(&post.ID, &post.Circle, &post.Description, &post.TimeStamp); err != nil {
            return nil,err
        }
        posts = append(posts, post)
    }
    return posts, nil
}
```

Select:

```golang
func (cdb *CirclesDB) GetPostsForUser(email string) ([]post.UserPost, error) {
    query :=
        `SELECT posts.rowid, circle, description, timestamp
        FROM posts
        WHERE author = ?
        ORDER BY
        timestamp DESC
        `
    rows, err := cdb.db.Query(query, email)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    var posts []post.UserPost
    defer rows.Close()
    for rows.Next() {
        var post post.UserPost
        if err := rows.Scan(&post.ID, &post.Circle, &post.Description, &post.TimeStamp); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        posts = append(posts, post)
    }
    return posts, nil
}
```

these are the `query` and `exec` methods:

```golang
func (cdb *CirclesDB) exec(stmt string, args ...any) (*sql.Result, error) {
    res, err := cdb.db.ExecContext(cdb.ctx, stmt, args...)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &res, nil
}

func (cdb *CirclesDB) query(stmt string, args ...any) (*sql.Rows, error) {
    res, err := cdb.db.QueryContext(cdb.ctx, stmt, args...)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return res, nil
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your "second attempt" but you should understand that it is still two queries (separated by a semicolon). We can't tell you why it returns no rows without sample data to reproduce the problem. One possibility is your WHERE clause filtered out all results.

Comment: Well, if POSTS.ID column contains ROWID value, then DELETE removed all rows from table and SELECT returned nothing. If that's not the case, how can we reproduce what you are saying?

Comment: @Littlefoot that isn't the case; when I run the query to select the rows after running the query that deletes and selects with a semicolon between the queries, it returns all the rows that I would expect to be returned when running the DELETE and SELECT query separated by a semicolon. I updated the question to show that

Comment: @topsail ok, so the semicolon is still two queries, is it possible to produce what I'm trying to do in one query? Also. I updated the question to show that the WHERE clause does not filter out all results

Comment: You cannot perform a delete and a select in a single query, period. They are two separate things. What problem are you trying to solve by doing so?

Comment: @Stu not having to send two statements across the wire, I don't want to send two requests to the sql server if it could be done in one

Comment: In what way are you sending your statements? (what kind of wire are you using here?)

Comment: @topsail I'm using the `database/sql` package in go, and the database is a sqlite database that is hosted on turso. I would like to make as few network requests as possible

Comment: I tried your code in a test sqlite database and no issues sending two statements (in my case it was just `delete from Table1 where Id = 1; select * from Table1;` This worked fine. As a rule as you progress in sending complex multistatement commands to a database, you probably want to make sure you understand transactions in databases (if that is new to you). Although actually I don't know if a multistatement query sent to sqlite would implicitly all be involved in a single transaction or not ... hmmm I should find out too!

Comment: @boreddad420 then use a different RDBMS and put your multi-sql statements in a stored procedure and execute the procedure in a single round trip, ensuring you use the correct isolation level and transactions.

Comment: As a note, you should also understand how your package handle results when multiple statements are involved. This is non-intuitive. It may execute all statements but not send any results back, it may execute only the first, it may execute all statements but only send the last result back or the first result back ... or just to put it another way, you can't assume what will happen and so take some time to figure it out clearly.

Comment: Just a thought It's possible that with multistatement queries they must ALL be semi-colon terminated. You added a semi-colon after the first part but not the second. I seem to recall this being an issue somewhere (but probably it was postgres).

Comment: `I would like to make as few network requests as possible` => premature optimisation.  Make it work functionally correctly, optimise ***when and only when*** you can demonstrate that you are resource constrained somewhere.  I've seen junior developers waste so much time on prematurely optimising, only to find they no longer have time to optimise the areas of real need, or see their code obsoleted and the optimisations go unused and unseen.

Comment: @MatBailie sure, it can be considered a premature optimization, but I would rather learn more about making it efficient than settle for what I currently have. I appreciate that I shouldn't waste so much time on a single optimization, but I am trying to learn how to use SQL better as a whole with this question more than trying to reduce the number of network requests as possible

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to delete a row from a table and return the remaining rows [...] in one query

I'm sorry, but SQL does not provide for that.  Among the four primary DML statements,

- `DELETE` deletes rows but does not return any;
- `SELECT` returns rows but does not delete any;
- `INSERT` and `UPDATE` neither delete nor return rows.

With many DBMSs you could consider creating a stored procedure having the wanted effect, but

1. SQLite does not support stored procedures, and
2. within the SP, you would still be using at least two separate statements.

> My attempt at trying to combine the queries [by joining them with a semicolon] resulted in no rows being returned when there was definitely still rows in the table.

As discussed in comments, that is still two queries. Insufficient detail is provided about how you are executing that to determine why no rows are returned, but my first guess would be that only the first of the two queries is being executed at all.